# jcarousel lite continuous show next image

Tags: jquery, carousel, jcarousellite

Hi there I'm stuck with a problem that i cannot seem to fix. It seems simple, on the website vector-studio.eu i used a modified jcarousel lite script * you an get it from http://gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/ it does what it should. I made the script show next and previous slides dimmed (changed the opacity) using the afterEnd function

```
afterEnd: function(a){
 a.next().css({opacity:.1});
 a.prev().css({opacity:.1});
 a.animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
}
```

The problem is that when the slides reach the end the next one isn't showing until a click or interval activates it.

I've tried to edit the plugin but can't make it load the next slide before the action takes place and it looks unfinished when you look at the effect.

Comment: I'd probably just find another plugin if I couldn't get that one to work.. here is a link I found with a quick google search http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/